# Form gets submitted Multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

While clicking inside the form , the form automatically tried to resubmit , I cannot figure out which part of the code causes it to behave like this . In the createTable function , a table is created after the domain is given . But I am unable to select any of the controls in the output . I have attached the jsfiddle code link here :  http://jsfiddle.net/rasikaceg/S7kWM/

```
function createTable() {
document.getElementById("table_container").innerHTML = "";
var input_domain = document.forms["form1"]["DomainName"].value;
if (input_domain == null || input_domain == "") return;

var table = document.createElement("table"),
    tablehead = document.createElement("thead"),
    theadrow = document.createElement("tr"),
    th1 = document.createElement("th"),
    th2 = document.createElement("th"),
    th3 = document.createElement("th"),
    th4 = document.createElement("th");
th1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Website"));
th2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Enable/Disable Live Update for LM and CBD"));
th3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("From Date"));
th4.appendChild(document.createTextNode("To Date"));
theadrow.appendChild(th1);
theadrow.appendChild(th2);
theadrow.appendChild(th3);
theadrow.appendChild(th4);
tablehead.appendChild(theadrow);
table.appendChild(tablehead);

var names = ["website1", "website2"];
var container = document.getElementById("table_container");
var tablebody = document.createElement("tbody");
for (var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr"),
        column1 = document.createElement("td"),
        column2 = document.createElement("td"),
        column3 = document.createElement("td"),
        column4 = document.createElement("td"),
        checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = names[i];
    checkbox.value = names[i];
    checkbox.id = names[i];
    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.htmlFor = names[i];
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(names[i]));
    column1.appendChild(checkbox);
    column1.appendChild(label);

    var dropdown = document.createElement("select");
    dropdown.name = names[i] + "_select";
    var op1 = new Option();
    op1.value = "enable";
    op1.text = "enable";
    var op2 = new Option();
    op2.value = "disable";
    op2.text = "disable";
    dropdown.options.add(op1);
    dropdown.options.add(op2);
    column2.appendChild(dropdown);

    var datetime_from = document.createElement('input');
    datetime_from.type = "datetime-local";
    datetime_from.name = names[i] + "_from";
    column3.appendChild(datetime_from);


    var datetime_to = document.createElement('input');
    datetime_to.type = "datetime-local";
    datetime_to.name = names[i] + "_to";
    column4.appendChild(datetime_to);


    row.appendChild(column1);
    row.appendChild(column2);
    row.appendChild(column3);
    row.appendChild(column4);
    tablebody.appendChild(row);
}
table.appendChild(tablebody);
document.getElementById("table_container").appendChild(table);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `<form onClick="...">`?

What is it for?

Consider `onsubmit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have written. which delegates form for click event.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onClick="createTable();return myFunction();">
```

What you should do is

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="createTable();return myFunction();">
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/S7kWM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

On each click on your form the two functions get called. Your table is inside the form so on click on any element in the table also will call the functions. You should call those only on submit of the form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onClick="createTable();return myFunction();">
```

should be

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="createTable();return myFunction();">
```